# Send a variable number of POST array variables to their own array

Tags: php

I've got a dynamic form that allows a user to create as many form elements as they need -- then submit them. For this, I have prepared the input names as arrays like

```
<input name="title[]" ...
```

and posting them gives me output like

```
Array
(
[day] => 0
[project_id] => 5
[submit] => publish
[id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 5
    )

[title] => Array
    (
        [0] => Step 1
        [1] => Step 2
    )

[max_vol] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 3
    )

[description] => Array
    (
        [0] => df dofi dofidfoi 
        [1] => dfvpdofvdpfo osd pod 
    )

)
```

I've created something that allows me to just grab the post arrays like so

```
foreach( $_POST as $post_key ) {
    // ignore non-array post variables
    if( is_array( $post_key ) ) {
        foreach( $post_key as $form_value ) {
            echo "$form_value\n";
        }
    }
}

/* ouputs...
4
5
Step 1
Step 2
2
3
df dofi dofidfoi 
dfvpdofvdpfo osd pod 
*/
```

which nicely sorts the non-arrays from the arrays, but I can't figure out how to take this variable number of created form elements and prepare them into an array variable that looks something like...

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
      'id' => 4, 'title' => 'Step 1', 'max_vol' => '2', 'description' => 'df dofi dofidfoi'
  ),
  [1] => Array
  (
      'id' => 5, 'title' => 'Step 2', 'max_vol' => '3', 'description' => 'dfvpdofvdpfo osd pod'
  ),
  // could be more or less elements...
);
```

(I will be eventually passing these arrays to a MySQL query builder function).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a variable that is outside the scope of the foreach loop

```
$results = array();
foreach( $_POST as $post_key=>$post_value ) {
    // ignore non-array post variables
    if( is_array( $post_value ) ) {
        foreach( $post_value as $form_key=>$form_value ) {
            if (!isset($results[$form_key]))
            {
                $results[$form_key] = array();
            }   
            $results[$form_key][$post_key] = $form_value;
        }
    }
}

// results is your array variable
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over some significant `$_POST`-array key, for example - `id` and get the values from other `$_POST`-arrays with the same index:

```
$values = array();
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $k => $v) {
    $values[] = array(
        'id' => $v,
        'title' => $_POST['title'][$k],
        'max_vol' => $_POST['max_vol'][$k],
        'description' => $_POST['description'][$k],
    );
}

print_r($values);
```